How would you translate workplace and worksite in Chinese?
When speaking with people in the educational field, I notice some of us refers to "worksite" as the place they work at. Such as their school. However, I always thought that "workplace" would be more accurate.
Findings: While "worksite" and "workplace" can both make sense to describe the place someone works at.
The former "worksite" can lean toward the definition of an "construction site", an specific project location. It, however, also have the meaning of an "workplace"(?)
In contrast, the latter "workplace" is more accurately for where someone works at. (i.e. office, school, factory, etc...)

Contextual Chinese Translation:
工作场所 (Workplace) / 职场 (Work Environment)
工作场所 (Workplace): 进行工作的地方; physical site of your job.
职场 (Work Environment): 职业活动的环境; emphasizes professional work environment.
办公室 (Office)
办公室 (Office): 处理公务; The workplace where services or other related work are taken place, such as that of a paperwork.
  办 = 处理; to deal with. In here, the word "办" refers to dealing with matters.
 
  公 = 处理公务; Handling public affairs.

工地 (Worksite)
工地 (Worksite): construction site or a designated project location.
  工 = 生产劳动; labor; physical work

While in English also has the meaning of a workplace, as a 'site' is an synonym for 'place'. In Chinese, however, '工地' can only refer to construction as its first character '工' refers to physical work.

What are your thoughts on  translate and differentiate workplace and worksite in a Chinese setting?

Worksite link: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Worksite&redirect=no
Redirect to
Workplace link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workplace

But in dictionary,

workplace meaning:


the room, building etc where you work 工作场所

或者

A place where people work, such as an office or factory. 工作场所（如办公室、工厂等）


worksite meaning(这里关于worksite的解释和例子, 我感觉不准确):


an area where an industry is located or where work takes place 工地

For example:

Some workers are sent for three months to our worksite in Germany.一些工人被派到我们在德国的工地上干三个月。


The construction company decides to move heavy caterpillars into the worksite, an act which creates a lot of cacophonies for the residents. 营造公司决定将大型机具移至工地，造成了对当地居民的许多噪音

结论:
你问题中最后部分的工应该来自 worksite meaning 中 an area where an industry is located or where work takes place 包含的industry(工业).
在英文中Worksite 和 workplace 是一个意思, 都表示工作场所.
但在中文里, worksite 侧重工地, workplace 侧重 工作场所, 工作场所包含工地. 我感觉把worksite翻译为 工地 不准确. 要表达工地的话用building site可能比较好.

A building site is an area of land on which a building or a group of buildings is in the process of being built or altered. 建筑工地


I agree that building site (建筑工地) may be more accurate for 工地. However, I may have been confused because of how the dictionary in English gave so many synonyms for 工地. For example "construction site", "building site",  "worksite"(based on contex).

@Monokuma 中文意思只能作为参考，意思(meaning)要以英文解释为准，中文翻译好多错误的，有的英文翻译为中文的句子(或文章或段落)都不通顺。

根据我的观察，有一些英文字翻译到中文时会有些不准确性。不过呢，中文作为表意文字的潜力也很高。因此通过一些官方翻译，我们可以更明确得理解一些外来语的中文翻译。例如游戏中boss的官方翻译是“首领”。但在口语中“老大”也可以合理使用。正如宝可梦中的火箭队总是称呼他们的首领为“坂木老大”。
虽然中英翻译中有很多文化差异，但我认为他们仍然可以有个准确／适应的翻译。另外我想到的例子就是“小说”。在我阅读一些来自中文以外，但被翻译为中文的小说时，我发现书里的语法都是有被很精炼地修饰。不论是来自日文或者是英文的小说。翻译为中文时，句法／语法都有经过精心的修饰。
因此，我认为中文是可以作为参考，但也不可以说它不通顺。也许不通顺的翻译只是来自那些不太会翻译，不懂文化差异和语境的人吧。
(True, but I still believe Chinese can have great official translation as an logogramic language.)

@Monokuma 关于“ 因此，我认为中文是可以作为参考，但也不可以说它不通顺。也许不通顺的翻译只是来自那些不太会翻译，不懂文化差异和语境的人吧。” 我想说你应该没看到一些技术方面的英文书翻译为中文书，意思完全偏离了英文原版作者的意思，之前我看过一本书，叫做应该是第4版，印象中第一章(刚开始的部分)里有个句子关于闪电的翻译，错的很离谱，有兴趣的话你可以看看。这个错误不是关于通顺不通顺的问题，完全属于翻译错误，严重偏离原英文作者的意图。

在技术方面 我确实看过类似的错误翻译。它们偏向英语直译过来的。另外这让我想起一些比较不流畅的翻译。比如「调制解调器」（modem）。我认为「数据器」是更好的翻译

@Monokuma  关于第4版中我之前看到的一个错误，如果你有兴趣的话，可以看下这个链接 https://gofile.io/d/CkETYa ，链接里有英文版和中文版，英文版是在书中第9页的 2.2.1 Currents in Perspective 节中a lightning strike，对应的翻译是中文版的书中第5页，最下面一行，书上翻译是避雷器，我认为把a lightning strike翻译为避雷器完全就是错误的，正确的翻译应该是闪电，可以参考维基百科链接 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_strike ，我很有兴趣想听听你的看法。

Workplace - 工作场所 = "the work environment", where you work and interact with your fellow employees (usually refers to the same place)
Worksite - 工作场地 = "the work location", where you go to work (can be long-term or short-term. If it is short-term, it might change every day or a few times a day)
We say workplace bullying, but we don't say Worksite bullying because a Worksite only refers to a location, but a workplace including the people in that place
工地 = 施工場地 = construction site/ worksite (can be as big as a builds complex or as small as a road sign)
